# parse multiple elements of xml in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse multiple elements (id1 and id2) in such kind of xml:

> ```
> <name>
>     <id1>104634449</id2>
>     <id2>22014870</id2>
> </name>
> <name>
>     <id1>104634433</id2>
>     <id2>220143210</id2>
> </name>
> ```

I use such code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    isName = [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"];
    isId1 = [elementName isEqualToString:@"id1"];
    isId2 = [elementName isEqualToString:@"id2"];    
    if(isName){
        name = [Name new];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
        if (isName){
            [names addObject:name];
        }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (isId1){
        [name setId1:string];
    }
    if (isId2){
        [name setId2:string];
    }
}
```

But only one element (id1 or id2) is set in object name. What I do wrong?

In debug I get this:
id1 = @"\n"
id2 = @"22014870"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you finish to read id2 isName is set to NO, so you don't really add it to your array.

This is the sequence of actions:

1. The name element starts;
2. The id1 element starts;
3. The id1 element ends;
4. The id2 element starts;
5. The id2 element ends;
6. The name element ends.

At point 4 occurs the last assignment of isName, set to:

```
isName = [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"];
```

Which will result false.

**The corrected code**:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString: @"name"){
            [names addObject:name];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you get too deep in the bowels of XML parsing I would highly recommend using [GDataXMLNode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Source/XMLSupport) (also available as a CocoaPod)

Then, to get an idea of how to use it, check out this tutorial, [How To Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but it is really so much simpler to use this library provided by Google.

Comment: Eww. This is just a wrapper over libxml2, which is a faster, more robust, and more feature rich version of this. Take the time to learn how the built-in libraries work before suggesting slow-performing patch job. Just because it has the name 'Google' on it doesn't mean it's better, for example, GData doesn't have support for complex XPath queries (returning types other than string or node), while native libxml2 does.

Comment: Fair enough Richard, wrappers are sometimes very welcome though. I generally prefer to deal with performance problems as they arise, rather than spending time prematurely optimizing. I have not run into any performance issues yet using this for what I've needed it for. And of course "Google" doesn't immediately mean better, "consider" would have been a better choice of words than "highly recommend".